# Pattern search in reverse order in a certain range and get the line number on each match using sed

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I want to search the pattern in a certain range but in reverse order. For example if I give the range say the range I have given is 2,8 then I want that search should be performed in reverse order. I mean search should be performed from line number 8 to 2 and if any line match the pattern then print the line number

Let's say I have an input file like this..

```
Hello world
Hello Universe
Hello Universe
Hello Maths
Hello Physics
Hello Earth
Hello Universe
Hello Tennis
Hello God
Hello Teacher
```

So there are 10 lines in the file. Now I want  to search the input  `Hello Universe` between line 8 to 2. So the output should be the line numbers where we match the `Hello Universe`

So as per above example the output should be

```
7
3
2
```

I have tried this command `sed -n '!G;h;2,8{\|Hello Universe|=}' a.txt` but it actually perform the search in ascending order

I have searched on internet and found if we do `sed '1!G;h;$!d' a.txt` then it actually print the file in reverse order. Just want to modify this command such that it print the line number in reverse order on each pattern match.

So How can I modify the command. Please help

Comment: @terdon `\|perl: warning:|` is actually a string which I wanted to match in my real case. But to explain my doubt here I have taken the example of `Hello Universe` string. Thank you for pointing out. Corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all you want is to find the matches in the lines 200 to 250 of a text file, but starting *from* 250 and until 200, an easy solution would be to `tac` the file which just prints it in reverse order. You can then use `grep -n` to search for your pattern and print the line number and a little perl script to change the line number to the correct one in the original file. Something like this:

```
sed -n '200,250p' file | tac | grep -n "$pattern" | perl -pe 's/(^\d+)/251-$1/e'
```

If we create a test file with:

```
printf 'Line number %d\n' {1..400} > file
```

And then use `21` as the pattern, we should get back lines 210 to 219, and 221:

```
$ sed -n '200,250p' file | tac | grep -n 21 | perl -pe 's/(^\d+)/251-$1/e'
221:Line number 221
219:Line number 219
218:Line number 218
217:Line number 217
216:Line number 216
215:Line number 215
214:Line number 214
213:Line number 213
212:Line number 212
211:Line number 211
210:Line number 210
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer meets my requirement but just wondering if it possible only with `sed` I mean without using `tac`. Please provide your thought on this

Comment: I would guess it is indeed possible, @vivek, `sed` is very powerful, but I have no idea how. Add an example file and output to your question and maybe someone with better sed knowledge can answer.